# Managing focus within a compound component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a compound component and I'd like to be able to use the up and down keys to navigate focus between the child components of a wrapper.

I can do this by standard DOM manipulation - but it feels as though there ought to be a better way to do this with React. I'm guessing this would normally involve refs - but I can't see how such a solution would work. The code below shows a working way of solving this problem using DOM manipulation:

```js
const A = () => (
  <button data-hook="a" style={{ display: "block", width: "100%" }}>
    A
  </button>
);
const B = () => (
  <button data-hook="b" style={{ display: "block", width: "100%" }}>
    B
  </button>
);

const WrapperWithOnPress = (props) => {
  const handleKeyDown = (event) => {
    let index = null;

    const topLevel = event.target.closest('[data-hook="top-level"]');

    const allAChildren = Array.from(
      topLevel.querySelectorAll('[data-hook="a"]')
    );

    allAChildren.forEach((child, i) => {
      if (child === event.target) {
        index = i;
      }
    });

    console.log(index);

    let nextIndex = index;

    // up
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
      nextIndex = Math.max(0, index - 1);
    }

    // down
    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      nextIndex = Math.min(allAChildren.length - 1, index + 1);
    }

    allAChildren[nextIndex].focus();
  };

  return (
    <div onKeyDown={handleKeyDown} data-hook="top-level">
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <WrapperWithOnPress>
        <A />
        <B />
        <A />
        <A />
      </WrapperWithOnPress>
    </div>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

The main problem is that the wrapper of the compound component in question needs to be able to only move between certain types of component in the children - in my actual use case, this means moving between only header components when the up or down keys are pressed.

Is there a way to do this sort of thing without manually reaching out to the DOM?

I have heard that it is possible to do `child.type` where `child` is a react component. I've never previously used this, and it doesn't seem to work for this example for me.

[Here is the example if it helps.](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-resonance-12rpc?file=/src/App.js:0-1233)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the most React-friendly solution that came to my mind.

Consider that if you want to use browser's native "focus", you can't avoid using the `HTMLElement.focus()` API. If you want to emulate it, then you can use the index from state to change children styles.

Please let me know if you have any doubt.

```js
const style = { display: "block", width: "100%" };

const A = () => (
  <button style={style}>
    A
  </button>
);
const B = () => (
  <button style={style}>
    B
  </button>
);

function clamp(num, min, max) {
    if (num > max) {
        return min;
    }
    if (num < min) {
        return max;
    }
    return num;
}

const WrapperWithOnPress = (props) => {
  const [index, setIndex] = React.useState(0);
  
  const ref = React.useRef(null);

  const onKeyDownHandler = React.useCallback((event) => {
    let step = 0;
    
    if (event.keyCode === 38) {
      step = -1;
    }

    if (event.keyCode === 40) {
      step = 1;
    }
    
    if (step) {
      setIndex((previousIndex) => clamp(previousIndex + step, 0, props.children.length - 1));
    }
  }, []);
  
  const onFocusHandler = React.useCallback((event) => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const children = ref.current.children;
      const targetIndex = Array.from(children).indexOf(event.target);
      setIndex(targetIndex);
    }
  }, []);
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    if (ref.current) {
      const children = ref.current.children;
      if (children[index] !== document.activeElement) {
        children[index].focus();
      }
    }
  }, [index]);

  return (
    <div ref={ref} onKeyDown={onKeyDownHandler} onFocus={onFocusHandler}>
      {props.children}
    </div>
  );
};

function App() {
  return (
    <WrapperWithOnPress>
        <A />
        <B />
        <A />
        <A />
    </WrapperWithOnPress>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I can't see a way to make this _more_ react-centric and so it seems that a n fairly large amount of DOM-interaction is essential

Comment: @OliverRadini glad to read that it helped. I've just corrected a typo, you may want to re-check the code, specially the `children[index].focus();` part.